# Regex pattern to match name

Tags: regex

```
: Dog 172     Network type            : Infrastructure     Authentication          : WPA2-Personal     Encryption              : CCMP      BSSID 1                 : FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF          Signal             : 91%            Radio type         : 802.11n          Channel            : 1           Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11          Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
```

With this pattern:

```
^:\s+(\S+).*$
```

I can match Dog, but how can I match the whole name of network?

I tried some stuff, but I always matched something else.

Comment: Do you mean you need `Dog 172`? `^:\s+(\S.*?)\s*Network type`?

Comment: I am so dumb, I can use look ahead with ur code, thanks.

Comment: Why lookahead? Can't you get Group 1 value?

Comment: Please show me your code, I see you are still struggling to make it work.

Comment: I use `(?<=: ).*?(?=[\s]{5}Network type)`, but I don't know if urs would be faster.

Comment: What is the language? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^:\s+(\S.*?)\s*Network type
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oX9vLG/1).

It will match

- `^` - start of string
- `:` - a colon
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S.*?)` - Group 1: one non-whitespace char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `Network type` - a literal string.

The result is in Group 1.

Comment: Is look ahead slower than ur pattern?

Comment: @JohnDoe Lookaheads are necessary when you need overlapping matches or when you can't access groups. You can, judging by the initial regex.